# How I can create bulk action links on orders page using API in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

How I can create bulk action links on orders page using API in Shopify? I found only how to create [bulk action links manual](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/app-extensions/shopify-admin/bulk-action-links)

Answer (score 0):

You can only create links using your partner dashboard settings for the App. Lately Shopify has taken to calling them **Extensions**. Shopify takes the links you create (**Extensions**) and inserts them for you. You do not need an API call to make a link.

Comment: I need to create this links in extension app programmatically not manual

Comment: There is no need to do this programmatically. You control the App. Use the GUI from Shopify. I have asked for access to these links for years, but so far, not possible. So stop thinking about it for now, and just use the GUI.